# Error while using images

Tags: android

I am getting the below error while using the images in the android code.

```
08-20 11:47:59.902: E/AndroidRuntime(2268): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-20 11:47:59.902: E/AndroidRuntime(2268):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-20 11:47:59.902: E/AndroidRuntime(2268):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:575)
08-20 11:47:59.902: E/AndroidRuntime(2268):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:410)
08-20 11:47:59.902: E/AndroidRuntime(2268):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
```

However my image file size is 5 kb and format is .png, I am rendering the image from the drawable folder to `ImageView`. However standard icon image is rendering successfully. P

Here is image view code

Android code I am using is `imgView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);`

Comment: Are you using listview for showing this image?

Comment: yes. I am using list view,

Comment: Can you show your loop ? Or the code arround setImageRes

Answer (score 0):

1st try this.Before setting image recycle the bitmap.

```
if(imgView!= null) {
    ((BitmapDrawable)imgView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
     imgView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
}
```

if this doesn't work then do this.Call the garbage collector manually. Though this is very bad practice.

```
imgView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
System.gc();
```

But the best practice is to resize the image before showing it